# Questionable DDWRT WAN Domain Name

Tags: dd-wrt

I'm wondering if someone can tell me why I would be seeing this name or any other domain name under this section. I haven't made any changes or assigned any domain names on my side.

I've had issues before where the WAN Domain Name would be something else entirely. 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmJM2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using DHCP on the WAN side and get assigned a domain name as option 15 ("domain-name") from your upstream provider.

You can safely ignore it when replacing it with whatever you want as a fixed value. IIRC the DHCP client in DD-WRT even allows you to ignore all or some options.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.